# Herkunft von "aber richtig"

Tags: etymology, phrase, conjunction

Gibt es einen identifizierbaren Ursprung für die nachgestellte Floskel ***aber richtig***, der bspw. ein Substantiv, Infinitiv, Imperativ oder Partizip vorausgeht?

Man findet dies bspw. als Buchtitel und mal mit Komma, mal mit Gedankenstrich, mal ohne, sowie mit und ohne Ausrufezeichen am Ende:

- Abnehmen – aber richtig
- Fasten – aber richtig
- Manipulieren – aber richtig
- Nachmachen – aber richtig
- Widerlegen – aber richtig
- Vögel füttern – aber richtig
- Flöte üben – aber richtig
- Schwarz ärgern – aber richtig
- Smartphones – aber richtig
- Junk-Food – aber richtig
- Facebook – aber richtig
- Selbstverliebt – aber richtig
- Wünsch es dir einfach – aber richtig

Es gibt daneben auch die Form mit Komparativ statt *richtig*, z.B. ***weniger, aber besser*** oder ***laufen aber härter***, sowie Konstrukte mit *in*, z.B. ***noch einmal, aber in gut***. Ich weiß nicht, was davon älter oder gängiger ist.

Comment: Als Kommentar, da nur Vermutung aus blasser Erinnerung: Ich glaube, dass diese Formulierung eine Erfindung der Buchtitler und Werbetexter der 1970er war, und zuerst in solchen Buchtiteln wie "Heimwerken, aber richtig!" o.Ä.  aufgetaucht ist.

Comment: @tofro: Offenkundig eine falsche Vermutung/Erinnerung: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22aber+richtig%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1904,cd_max:1976&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=cr&ei=RzzaVvzqIY7b6QTonp7wAw

Comment: Erinnern, aber richtig! Allerdings scheint die Spur der "Selbsthilfebücher" nicht so schlecht zu sein..... Wusste gar nicht, dass es die schon so lange gibt.

Comment: Im Englischen gibt es das ähnliche *idiom* `"the right way"`.

Comment: Oder weniger formell: `"-- done right!"`

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man sich auf die diversen Online-Bibliothekskataloge verlassen kann, erschien erstmals 1926 ein Buch mit der Floskel "aber richtig" im Titel: Robert Skutezky: "*Organisieren - aber richtig*" Bd. 1 (1926). Interessanterweise datiert auch der früheste Treffer für diese Floskel im DWDS aus den 1920er Jahren. Eine genauere Herkunftsbestimmung müsste wahrscheinlich die Literatur aus den 1920er Jahren, insbesondere Zeitungen und Zeitschriften, intensiv auswerten.

Answer (score -1):

Ich kenne den Ausdruck: Wennschon, dennschon!

Bzw. Wenn schon, dann richtig!

Ursprung? Unklar.

In English you have the saying. If something is worth doing, it's worth doing right. Both have the same intention.

That leads me to thing that the intention of saying. If you are doing it, you might as well do it right could be international.

In Spanish you have:
http://dix.osola.com/index.php?opt=&trans=1&search=de+hacerlo%2C+hacerlo+bien

de hacerlo, hacerlo bien.

I'd call this a truism.